# wput speed result as pass or fail

Tags: linux, bash

I'm using the following to output the result of an upload speed test

```
wput 10MB.zip ftp://user:pass@host 2>&1 | grep '\([0-9.]\+[KM]/s\)'
```

which returns

```
18:14:38 (10MB.zip) - '10.49M/s' [10485760]
Transfered 10,485,760 bytes in 1 file at 10.23M/s
```

I'd like to have the result `10.23M/s` (i.e. the speed) echoed, and a comparison result:

```
if speed=>5 MB/s then echo "pass" else echo "fail"
```

So, the final output would be:

```
PASS 7 M/s
```

---

23/01/2013

ideally i'd like it all done on a single line so far i've got

```
wput 100M.bin ftp://test:test@0.0.0.0 2>&1 | grep -o '\([0-9.]\+[KM]/s\)$' | awk ' { if (($1 > 5) && ($2 == "M/s")) { printf("FAST %s\n ", $0); }}'
```

however it doesn't output anything if I remove

```
&& ($2 == "M/s"))
```

it works but I obviously want to it output above 5M/s and as it is it would still echo fast if it was over 1K/s. Can someone tell me what i've missed.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
# Over 5M/s
$ cat pass
18:14:38 (10MB.zip) - '10.49M/s' [10485760]
Transfered 10,485,760 bytes in 1 file at 10.23M/s

$ awk 'END{f="FAIL "$NF;p="PASS "$NF;if($NF~/K\/s/){print f;exit};gsub(/M\/s/,"");print(int($NF)>5?p:f)}' pass
PASS 10.23M/s

# Under 5M/s
$ cat fail
18:14:38 (10MB.zip) - '3.49M/s' [10485760]
Transfered 10,485,760 bytes in 1 file at 3.23M/s 

$ awk 'END{f="FAIL "$NF;p="PASS "$NF;if($NF~/K\/s/){print f;exit};gsub(/M\/s/,"");print(int($NF)>5?p:f)}' fail
FAIL 3.23M/s

# Also Handle K/s 
$ cat slow
18:14:38 (10MB.zip) - '3.49M/s' [10485760]
Transfered 10,485,760 bytes in 1 file at 8.23K/s

$ awk 'END{f="FAIL "$NF;p="PASS "$NF;if($NF~/K\/s/){print f;exit};gsub(/M\/s/,"");print(int($NF)>5?p:f)}' slow

FAIL 8.23K/s
```

Not sure where you get `7 M/s` from?

Answer (score 1):

According to @Rubens, you can use [`grep -o`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) with your regex to show the speed, just append `$` for end of line

```
wput 10MB.zip ftp://user:pass@host 2>&1 | grep -o '\([0-9.]\+[KM]/s\)$'
```

With [`perl`](http://perldoc.perl.org/) you can easily do the remaining stuff

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    if (m!\s+((\d+\.\d+)([KM])/s)$!) {
        if ($2 > 5 && $3 eq 'M') {
            print "PASS $1\n";
        } else {
            print "FAIL $1\n";
        }
    }
}
```

and then call it

```
wput 10MB.zip ftp://user:pass@host 2>&1 | perl script.pl
```

Comment: Yes, you can use `grep` to do so; just use `grep -o`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question it just prints the speed *(as @Rubens points out can be done with the addition of `-o` to `grep`)*

Comment: @Lurch Since this is a new (awk) question, I have added another answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to the question update.

With the `awk` program, you haven't split the speed into numeric and unit value. It is just one string.

Because fast speed is greater than `5 M/s`, you can ignore `K/s` and extract the speed by splitting at the character `M`. Then you have the speed in `$1` and can compare it

```
wput 100M.bin ftp://test:test@0.0.0.0 2>&1 | grep -o '[0-9.]\+M/s$' | awk -F '/M/' '{ if ($1 > 5) { printf("FAST %s\n ", $0); }}'
```